# extracting value from url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm intercepting user clicks on pagination links and I need to extract only page number from that link which is always set inside page variable.

so inside my js I have 
....

```
var a = $a.attr("href");
```

..
which ouputs this

```
/Home/GetTabData?page=2&activeTab=House
```

so how can I extract only this number from after **page=**

If it's matter keep in mind that this number can be two or three digit long and activeTab is dynamic value.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some *regex*, you can extract it like:

```
var num = +(a.match(/page=(\d+)&/)[1]);
```

In the above code:

1. `/page=(\d+)&/` is a regex that matches the number (one or more numeric characters) between `"page="` and `"&"`. Note that we have grouped the `(\d+)` which is the number we are after
2. The `+` prefix is for converting the extracted string into a number. This is similar to using `parseInt()`

Answer (score 0):

after you have the link, in this case a, you simply search the string for 'page=' using indexOf() then make a substring from there to the next & character.

```
var start, end, value;
start = a.indexOf("page=");
end = a.indexOf("&", start);
value = a.substring(start+5, end);
```

more info on IndexOf()
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp